# Needing to send a JSON request in perl

Tags: json, perl, perl-module

I am having trouble making this work I keep getting a 400 bad request response. Any help is greatly appreciated as this is my first attempt at both coding perl and using JSON. I had to remove some of the sensitive data as this is something for work. The point of this script is to simply hit the URL sending the POST data via JSON and print the response.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use HTTP::Request::Common;
use JSON;


my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $req = POST 'URL IS HERE';
my $res = $ua->request($req);
my $json = '{"warehouseId": "ID",
"tagMap":
  {"cameraId":["Name of camera"]
  },
"searchStartTimeStamp": 0,
"searchEndTimeStamp": 100000000000000,
"pageSize": 1,
 "client": 
  {"id": "username",
   "type": "person"}
}';


$req->header( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' );
$req->content( $json );


    if ($res->is_success) {
print $req->content( $json );

    print $res->content;
} else {
    print $res->status_line . "\n";
}
exit 0;
```

Comment: This is the output from the script   "400 Bad Request"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You perform the request before you have fully populated it! This line does the request:

```
my $res = $ua->request($req);
```

but a few lines later, you fill some fields:

```
$req->header( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' );
$req->content( $json );
```

Try swapping that around:

```
my $json = ...;

my $ua = LWP::UserAgent->new;
my $req = POST 'URL IS HERE';    
$req->header( 'Content-Type' => 'application/json' );
$req->content( $json );

my $res = $ua->request($req);
```

---

Oh, never `$res->content`. The value of that method is not generally something usable. You *always* want

```
$res->decoded_content;
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! After swapping them and changing to decoded_content this is now the ouput from running the script.            
Global symbol "$req" requires explicit package name at lwp.cgi line 9.  
Global symbol "$req" requires explicit package name at lwp.cgi line 10.  
Global symbol "$json" requires explicit package name at lwp.cgi line 10.

Comment: @root Did you forget a semicolon? Also, you still need to declare and initialize `$json` before putting it into your request.

Comment: What I did was move the two $req lines to be below the use section

Comment: @root That obviously doesn't work. I updated my post with example code.

Comment: Awesome that worked I had to move the rest of the my decloration above that as well. Thanks again for your help! You are a life saver!

Comment: One other minor issue while yes the query works I keep getting this message any idea on how to fix it?  Content-Length header value was wrong, fixed at /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2/LWP/Protocol/http.pm line 207.